# How to initialize my contract with front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, truffle

I've compiled and deployed my contract and tested it successfully and also connect Metamask to ganache and all works fine.

The problem is when I try to interact my smart contract with my front end I always end up by getting errors and I guess it's because of my  initialization code in the App.js.

This is my initialization. I'm using truffle v 5.3.11 and web3 1.0.0 beta

```
 initSupplyChain: function () {
        
        var jsonSupplyChain = '../../build/contracts/SupplyChain.json';

        /// JSONfy the smart contracts
        $.getJSON(jsonSupplyChain, function (data) {
            console.log('data', data);
            var SupplyChainArtifact = data;
            App.Contracts.SupplyChain = TruffleContract(SupplyChainArtifact);
            App.Contracts.SupplyChain.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

         App.fetchItemBufferOne();
           App.fetchItemBufferTwo();
           App.fetchEvents();

        });

        return App.bindEvents();
    },
```